# Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.20.1)

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to install `numpy` but it gives me an error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.20.1)
```

And when I ran a Python script, it threw `ModuleError: no module named numpy`.

Comment: are you sure you are activating your conda environment before importing

Comment: ı dont understand you. ı use vscode also. pls explain me.

Comment: Are you sure your VSCode is using the same Python?  It's pretty easy to get multiple Python installations.